# Google or GooglePlus sign in for iOS Application

Tags: ios, google-plus-signin, google-signin

the requirement is to implement Sign In With Google Plus in iOS Application. I am going to ask an email, first name, last name, profile picture.

I see that there is a [Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) and [Google Plus Sign In](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in). But which one should i use? I have also found [migration guide from Google+ to Google Sign In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide). But i don't see any suggestion on whether i should use one or another, and whether people should migrate to Google Sign In.

Please help me in making a decision. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using Google Sign-in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

You can use it for both using different scopes. In your case, I would use

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
```

Google Plus Sign-in requires a Google+ Account not only a Google Account.

Comment: They've put this on their site: Note: If you just want to allow users to sign in to your app using their Google accounts, and don't need any Google+ features, use Google Sign-In.